# Creating a Database on sqlite iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, sqlite

i'm following a iOS 6 video tutorial, on how to use SQlite3, on my App, but i think the process of creating a database have changed on iOS 7, because i simply cannot make my app work.

This is the code:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    sqlite3 *db_name;
}
-(NSString *)filePath { // sqlite database path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bp.sql"];
}

-(void)openDB { // Create or load db
    if(sqlite3_open([[self filePath]UTF8String], &db_name)!= SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db_name);
        NSLog(@"DB failed to open");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DB openend");
    }
}
```

Both functions are declared in the headers. And i always get DB FAILED TO OPEN. Should i do something different?

Comment: Hint:  If you suspect that something is different between 6 and 7, just tell Xcode to run an iOS 6 simulator session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have **NSDocumentationDirectory** as an argument in **NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains** function, where you should replace it with **NSDocumentDirectory**.

Like this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

For more info on the different constants available to get different file paths look at the [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-BAJHBFCH) by Apple.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the answer! this was the problem.

Comment: You're most welcome. Because the names are similar between the two enums it's easily missed, especially when you're coding fast and Xcode is auto completing as you type.